# Spark job aborted - can't find reason in the logs

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

My Spark job gets aborted while writing to parquet files. It only happens when I try to run on a large dataset. When running on a reduced data set, the job goes through.

I've been looking through logs, but I can't find any reason for this job failing. Maybe someone can give me a hint where to look for more clues. Here's the job output:

```
INFO:de_etl.smart_meters.data_processing:Save intermediate to "smart_meters_full_reload/stage1"
18/07/14 13:38:24 WARN AzureFileSystemThreadPoolExecutor: Disabling threads for Delete operation as thread count 0 is <= 1
18/07/14 15:48:50 WARN AzureFileSystemThreadPoolExecutor: Disabling threads for Delete operation as thread count 0 is <= 1
18/07/14 15:48:51 WARN NativeAzureFileSystem: Attempt to delete non-existent file user/a7adu31/.sparkStaging/application_1531498233339_0285/__spark_conf__.zip
18/07/14 15:48:51 WARN NativeAzureFileSystem: Attempt to delete non-existent file user/a7adu31/.sparkStaging/application_1531498233339_0285/mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar
18/07/14 15:48:51 WARN NativeAzureFileSystem: Attempt to delete non-existent file user/a7adu31/.sparkStaging/application_1531498233339_0285/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip
18/07/14 15:48:52 WARN NativeAzureFileSystem: Attempt to delete non-existent file user/a7adu31/.sparkStaging/application_1531498233339_0285/pyspark.zip
18/07/14 15:48:52 WARN NativeAzureFileSystem: Attempt to delete non-existent file user/a7adu31/.sparkStaging/application_1531498233339_0285/spark-avro_2.11-3.2.0.jar
18/07/14 15:48:52 ERROR YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Yarn application has already exited with state FINISHED!
18/07/14 15:48:54 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_7_2 !
18/07/14 15:48:54 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_7_109 !
```

... a lot more of those ...

```
18/07/14 15:48:55 WARN BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: No more replicas available for rdd_7_64 !
18/07/14 15:49:00 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job null.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 4 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:820)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:818)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop(DAGScheduler.scala:818)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onStop(DAGScheduler.scala:1750)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop.stop(EventLoop.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$8.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1928)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1317)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend$MonitorThread.run(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeInFileFormat(DataSource.scala:437)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:473)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:609)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:508)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18/07/14 15:49:00 WARN AzureFileSystemThreadPoolExecutor: Disabling threads for Delete operation as thread count 0 is <= 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reload_smart_meter_validated_base_linear.py", line 3, in <module>
    smart_meters.data_processing.full_reload()
  File "/datadisk/home/a7adu31/src/de-etl-smart-meters/de_etl/smart_meters/data_processing.py", line 91, in full_reload
    stage2_tmp_path="smart_meters_full_reload/stage2")
  File "/datadisk/home/a7adu31/src/de-etl-smart-meters/de_etl/smart_meters/data_processing.py", line 121, in reload
   output_path=stage1_tmp_path)
  File "/datadisk/home/a7adu31/src/de-etl-smart-meters/de_etl/smart_meters/data_processing.py", line 174, in reload_stage1
    sm_mandates_incl.write.parquet(output_path, mode='overwrite')
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 691, in parquet
    self._jwrite.parquet(path)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o564.parquet. 
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:213)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.writeInFileFormat(DataSource.scala:437)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:473)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:116)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:609)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:508)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job 4 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:820)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:818)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.cleanUpAfterSchedulerStop(DAGScheduler.scala:818)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onStop(DAGScheduler.scala:1750)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop.stop(EventLoop.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$8.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1928)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1317)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend$MonitorThread.run(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2029)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply$mcV$sp(FileFormatWriter.scala:186)
    ... 45 more
```

Comment: What is the size of your dataset and how many partitions do you want to save to? Can you give the command you use to save data?

Comment: I have from 180 to ca 1000 partitions, depending on whether I try the whole dataset or a part of it (there is one partition per day and we have 3 years of data). There are a couple of million rows per partition. I'm using PySpark. This is the line that write the files to parquet: ```sm_mandates_incl.write.parquet(output_path, mode='overwrite')```

This is a HDInsights cluster, and 'output_path' is Azure's BLOB storage.

Comment: Is the stage that includes saving of the data long and has high Peak Execution Memory? I had often problems saving files when the stage was long with many transformations, high Peak Execution Memory (In my case > 1Gb) and a shuffle or a join. If possible you might break your last stage with `cache` and `rdd.count()`.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely long and has many transformations. Not sure about Peak Execution Memory. But I'll definitely try to add cache() before write. Thanks for the tip!